# ios 7 browser-kit black borders around div elements

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, jquery-masonry

I'm getting a strange bug in the browsers in iOS7 where black lines are appearing around div elements. But when you zoom in to an element, these lines are disappearing. Does anyone have an idea what causes this strange bug? In iOS6 there weren't any lines appearing.
It's happening on this url: http://www.tristanfrencken.com/

Hopefully someone could help me with this!

Comment: Can you give some more details such as what border style your using etc.? Also, maybe include a screenshot or two?

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot but i wasn't allowed yet to post an image. The problem seemed to be lying in the jquery Isotop plugin i was using. I changed it to the masonry plugin and now the borders are gone. There is still a border visible at the bottom of the header which has position: fixed. So i think it has something to do with this position. I don't have any border styles in my CSS for these elements.

Answer (score 4):

Bizarrely, this seems to be triggered when an element is fixed AND has a background color, but only in IOS7 and not if it has a background image. I'd chalk it up as a bug in the browser, but as a workaround for now you could use a solid white image, tiled, as your header background.

Comment: by fixed you mean position:absolute ?

Comment: No, I mean position: fixed

Comment: hmmm, I've deleted all elements with position:fixed and still having this issue, do you have any further tips maybe ? :)

Comment: Only to replace background colours with a solid image? I've only seen the problem with position: fixed though, so maybe your issue is different.

Comment: Thx Greg for your help, it seems to be common problem, I've done some testing on e.g. cnn.com and there is also this problem. 

I've found that this know and fixed problem in webkit : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=124541 so we have to just wait for some patches for safari :)

Answer (score 3):

We hade the same problem in our web app where container div-elements with background color and fixed positioning would get black borders at various zoom values in iOS 7.

Our first solution involved converting background colors to base64 urls which worked fairly well but wasn't flexible enough.

Instead we got rid of the black borders by applying `border-radius: 1px;` to the container elements which removed all black borders. The value is low enough to not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in iOS7 as well as in the newest Safari on OSX Maverick. Overlapping elements with background color seem to 'thicken' their outlines causing this strange behaviour. I am desperately looking for a solution to this.

I started a new topic about it here
[iOS7 / Mavericks Safari strange element border behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118199/ios7-maverick-safari-strange-element-border-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and it had to do with the meta tag allowing zoom

Apparently iOS Safari has a problem with resizing things and creates that artifact

Applying a meta tag to disable zoom solved my problem (user-scalable = no)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, especially if you want your page to be zoomable...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is problem directly in webkit ( https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=124541 ).

Answer (score 0):

Use "background-image" property with the same gradient values:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #your_color, #your_color);
```