# iOS7 / Mavericks Safari strange element border behaviour

Tags: html, ios, css, ios7, webkit

This seems to be a bug in iOS7 mobile Safari and Mavericks Safari

Another topic touching the issue:
[ios 7 browser-kit black borders around div elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088381/ios-7-browser-kit-black-borders-around-div-elements)

As soon as elements with background color overlap on their edges, it causes a 'thickening' of their overlapping border, causing that weird black lines.

Strangest of all: when zooming around the borders seem to go away and come back in seemingly random behaviour.

EDIT: it seems it has to do with safari background image size rounding problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099348/1515187

Anyone knows of this bug and any workaround?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: trying to reproduce in a fiddle right now

Answer (score 0):

I came across this bug just now.
It appears in ios7 when I try to modify the .
you can set the viewport to
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

that can solve the problem.

If you do need to modify it.
The bug appears in fixed elements(position:fixed/relative/absolute).
you can set the background:url(about:blank) to your fixed element to solve this problem .However, the bug reappears if you try to set a background color.
So,set the empty background and no more.

In my case,I avoid the bug by setting the background:url(about:blank) in the fixed div and set my background in the inner one(which is not fixed).

Hope I can help