# Border visited link on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, border

I'm working on a responsive design.
And there is one problem which is not present on my desktop PC or my Android phone.

Only on iPhone there are a black borders around the boxes on visited links.
I can't find a way, how to remove those black borders.

On my Screenshot you can see, what I mean. Is there maybe a special css command?

[image: Comparison]

**HTML:**

```
<a href="link1.html">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box menu">
    <div class="opacity"></div>
    <div class="box_bg">
      <i class="fa fa-info"></i><br/>
      infomappe
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="link2.html">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box menu">
    <div class="opacity"></div>
    <div class="box_bg">
      <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i><br/>
      Visitenkarte
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background:transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
     -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
      -ms-transition: all .15s linear;
       -o-transition: all .15s linear;
          transition: all .15s linear;
}

a:visited, a:focus, a:active {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline-color: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* Boxes */

.box{
  height:100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;       
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box i{
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-bottom:8px;
}

.box_bg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
.menu .opacity{
  border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;    
}
```

Comment: I'm presuming one of your classes not shown here must be setting a border on the .box or the .menu, without providing a colour. This means the browser will instead inherit the text colour. Your browsers developer tools should assist you in finding where this mystery border is coming from.

Comment: Had a quick look and found [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22837912/3436942)

Comment: add this code into your stylesheet .menu .opacity {
    border: 1px solid #EFEFEF !important;
}

Comment: @Robin Neal I've inserted all relevant classes. I serached for **border** in my complete css file, but there is nothing. I cannot use the developer tools on the iphone. On his ios computer are no borders.

Comment: jbutler483
tried it, no changes...

@Dhaarani no changes... :/

Comment: use this <meta name="viewport" content="width=640px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: @Dhaarani then the page is too wide for mobile phones. the borders also don't disapear.